# Put Alert Warning when Clicking in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui

I have here an image uploader. My problem is that I wanted to let the `alert` appear first after clicking if you haven't selected from the `autocomplete`.
Currently the `alert` appears after choosing an image.

Codesandbox [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-added-array-of-object-inside-another-aray-in-react-forked-rmcis?file=/src/components/UploadImage/index.js)

```
  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();

    if (!value) {
      setOpen(true);
    } else {
      if (!e) return;
      const files = e.nativeEvent.dataTransfer.files;
      onUploadImage(files);
    }
  };

  const browseFiles = (e) => {
    if (!value) {
      setOpen(true);
    } else {
      if (!e) return;
      const files = e.currentTarget.files;
      onUploadImage(files);
    }
    e.target.value = null;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by adding an onClick to the button that wraps the file input:

```
     <Button
      size="medium"
      variant="outlined"
      component="label"
      color="primary"
      onClick={(e) => {
        if (!value) {
          setOpen(true);
          e.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
        }
      }}
    >
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        multiple
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange={(e) => browseFiles(e)}
      />
      Browse files
    </Button>
```